# i wanted to make horizontal gradient text color?

Tags: text-editor

I was trying to make horizontal gradient text. And I made needed nodes, but nodes didn't color of the text.

[image: nodes]
[image: final result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Gradient Texture Node to Linear.
Edit:
After that use the Z rotation in the Mapping Node to get a vertical or horizontal gradient.
[image]

Comment: I can't make it horizontal with Gradient Texture Node being linear.

Comment: Can you post your blend file then? Because it works for me

Comment: Here   http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47094

Comment: The file works when set to Linear, I just tested:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47097

Comment: It works but i stil can't find right coordinats to it be horizontal. blue on top and white on the bottom.

Comment: Just se the Z rotation in the mapping node to 90 or 270

Comment: Finally worked it out with 270 and reversing ColorRamp.